# filter the top x from a grouping based on a column with the number to keep of each group - DPLYR

Tags: r, dplyr

I used the top_n function to have dplyr filter or slice a group based on a variable. Take this sample code for example. There are two groups (exam_number) and I need to automate so that for each group it retains only the top "keep" of  "total_score". For example the first group "19-7415" would keep the top five "total_score" rows and "21-320" would keep the top 6

```
structure(list(exam_number = c("19-7415", "19-7415", "19-7415", 
"19-7415", "19-7415", "19-7415", "19-7415", "21-320", "21-320", 
"21-320", "21-320", "21-320", "21-320", "21-320"), class_code = c("7415", 
"7415", "7415", "7415", "7415", "7415", "7415", "320", "320", 
"320", "320", "320", "320", "320"), total_score = c(84.98, 83.58, 
80.27, 79.66, 76.52, 76.23, 75.68, 85.79, 84.88, 83.38, 81.08, 
79.91, 79.69, 69.98), keep = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), groups = structure(list(
exam_number = c("19-7415", "21-320"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:7, 8:14), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

I had used top_n to do this before but it looks like they are no longer using it and recommend slice_max. However I don't see how to make the number you slice relative to a grouping as I was able to with top_n like below:

```
data %>% group_by(exam_number) %>% top_n(wt = total_score, n = keep)
```

Here is what I tried with slice_max

```
data %>% group_by(exam_number) %>% top_n(order_by = total_score, n = keep)

Error in `slice_max()`:
! `n` must be a round number, not a function.
```

Comment: `data %>% group_by(exam_number) %>% slice_max(order_by = total_score, n = keep)`

Comment: @GregorThomas Should have mentioned I tried that and got an error "n must be a round number, not a function"

Comment: Ah, I see, `keep` is in your data frame. Try `data %>% arrange(desc(total_score)) %>% filter(row_number() <= keep)`

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you! What a clever use of rownumber()! This worked.